Factor analysis for repeated measures data?
I have created a rubric with 9 criteria for the evaluation of presentations, which I would now like to validate.
I want to do a factor analysis for this.
What data do I have? All 66 people rated 4 presentations each. The 4 presentations are the same for all 66 people.
Can I do a single EFA or CFA with all 4 presentations?
I am not sure if this is really a repeated measures design. Experience has shown that the factor structure also depends on the presentation being assessed. Therefore, if at all possible, I would like to do a single factor analysis where I integrate the ratings from all 4 presentations.
Would be great if someone could help

If the factor structure depends on the presentation, that is a strong argument against combining them, even if it is possible.  Rather, it is arguing for trying to explain why the structure is different.
It seems analogous to taking the mean of things. If the things are very disparate, then the mean can still be calculated, no problem. But what use is it?
You can take the average weight of a cherry, a banana, a pineapple, and a watermelon, but it won't help you understand your fruit salad.
